# Using PyInstaller with Kivy (helloWorld.py)

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a simple app written in Kivy for Windows. For packaging to an executable file I've chosen PyInstaller.

I've been also trying to follow [this tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html), but with no success. I've been searching through several Stack Overflow topics, but didn't find a universal tutorial.

How can I package "Kivy hello world" into a standalone executable with PyInstaller? The `.spec` file is confusing to me. I have installed every package, and everything is working as python script.

Source code:

```
# helloWorld.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

I've made an exe file from this, but the window immediately disappears.

Comment: If the program crashes for some reason after packaging, look for a error in the log files in .kivy/logs in your user directory.

Comment: in your spec file set console=True. This will give you logging info as well.

Comment: Just have a look at this post. This might help you further. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39194161/5708480